# how to validate a UITextView so that it does not allow special characters like '&'?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have some UITextViews. Where User will enter data and this data will be submitted to database using web service.The database shows error with special characters like '&'. So I want to block user when he/she tries to submit data with this special characters or there should a message on submitting the data' I mean How to validate that textview? If somebody knows about it please help me. Thanx a lot.

Comment: You have now asked 12 questions and still accepted none of the answers. Several people took their time to help you. It would be a kind gesture to "accept" those answers that helped you. It is not complicated: Just click on that checkmark outline to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First way, mentioned all accepted charecters like below sample code and if found out of range characters put message to display.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string 
{
    NSCharacterSet * set = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"] invertedSet];
    if ([textField.text rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location != NSNotFound) 
    {
        NSLog(@"This string contains illegal characters");
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Or, go with Regular Expression and do the same thing in another way...

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string 
{
    if ([textField.text isMatchedByRegex:@"[^a-zA-Z0-9]"]) 
    {
        NSLog(@"This string contains illegal characters");
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: this is working partially as it does not validate the first character in the textfield

Comment: I mean if i enter only one character which is special character like &. It does not validate.